# error in displaying local wordpress website

Tags: localhost, wordpress, intranet

i have installed wordpress correctly on my Xubuntu 12.04 and it works perfectly normal for my system, when i access the same on another system then it doesn't show the page UI properly, means there is no JS or CSS displayed. did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Look at assets urls:

In Chrome, press F12 (Developer Tools), open tab - Network and look for missing files, they are red (if not shown, refresh page with dev tools opened).

I think you have wrong site name or site url in your wordpress configuration, and your instalation is looking for files from `http://localhost/wp-content`